# Creating a stub for editing office documents

Tags: c#, com, ms-word

I'm looking to create a synchronization mechanism for a document storage service.

The essential idea is that the user downloads a stub file say somefile.stub that contains a link to the file on the server.

When the stub file is clicked on an app on the users machine (associated with .stub) opens up looks in the file and downloads the document from the server in the background.

Once I've got the file locally I'd like to get windows to open up the file in the appropriate editor e.g. word. **I really don't want to have to save out the file and then open word or whatever via Process and a command line.**

Also, I'd like to be able to grab the document when its saved and send it back to the server to keep everything in synch.

I'd prefer to write the client application in c# if possible.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a service running continuosly on the client machine, that should orchestrate the stub file transfer and the opening of them. Opening with the proper program can be achieved by using [Process](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.aspx) with `StartInfo.UseShellExecute = true;`. You can also use a [FileSystemWhatcher](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.aspx) to be notified when the external app modify the file.

Comment: I've edited for clarity, I don't want to save a file and open with a command line.

Comment: I'm not talking about any command line, use Process with shell execute from within your code

Answer (score 0):

Here is one solution:

1. Create a Class 2 WebDAV Server and publish your MS Office documents via it.
2. In case you target MS Office 2013 you can use the following link to open documents for editing directly from your WebDAV server:

   ms-word:ofe|u|http://mywebdavserver.com/path/document.docx

This will eliminate download/upload steps and will work in the SharePoint-like manner. You also do not need to deploy any client application in this case.